# Destroy the effect when I scrolling down

Tags: jquery

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('#girl').delay(4000).fadeOut(4000);
        $('#new_girl').fadeIn(500);
    }
    else{

    }

});
```

When I load the page and scroll down after 4s then this function works fine But when I load the page and start scrolling when the page load then this works again. I want that, **If I scroll down without waiting 4 seconds**, then destroy this function.May be this logic should be set in the else statement.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

`$( window ).load(function() {` indicates that your code inside it will only execute when `window` is completely loaded

So you must have to wait.

What you can do is that write only this code

```
 if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('#girl').delay(4000).fadeOut(4000);
        $('#new_girl').fadeIn(500);
    }
    else{

    }
```

and make sure jQuery is included before this code

Maybe you will get JS error if elements with ID `#girl` and `#new_girl` are not loaded into DOM

Answer (score 0):

No.1 why you have used $("window").load method ..do you know it triggers event only after everything is loaded into the page ...like css,js and including images.

use document.ready method instead of it if you want to trigger it just after document loads.
else check out the orange button here and see the code [siteflu](http://siteflu.com)

Answer (score 0):

But that is also what your code is telling. What you could do is `$(document).ready(function(){`